can I run my python script using gunicorn and wsgi
I have a Python script which I want to run using Gunicorn. I have created a wsgi file as I am not using any framework. So I have 3 files in my folder: my Python script (app.py), Wsgi file (wsgi.py), and gunicorn configuration file (gunicorn.config.py). Now please explain how to connect all these files using gunicorn configuration file. I am using below command to run gunicorn:
gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py --pid gunicorn.pid wsgi:application

wsgi is the file and application is the function which accepts two positional parameters:
A dictionary containing CGI like variables; and
a callback function that will be used by the application to send HTTP status code/message and HTTP headers to the server.
This function returns the response body to the server as strings wrapped in an iterable.
I have imported my main function from my Python script which needs to be run from the app.py file in gunicorn config file.
Also below is my wsgi file code:
import os
from app import application

# Set environment variables
os.environ['DB_USER'] = ''
os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'] = ''
os.environ['DB_HOST'] = ''
os.environ['DB_NAME'] = ''
os.environ['DB_PORT'] = ''  
# The WSGI application callable
app = application`

application is a function defined in the app.py file which is calling my main function which is in the same file.
But using this process there is no error while running Gunicorn but I am not getting my output.
